# android - fragmenttabhost not showing inside my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

My classes

FragmentTabs - the fragment that will hold my FragmentTabHost

Its onCreateView method

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    fragmentTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    fragmentTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getFragmentManager());

    fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"), Fragment1.class, null);
    fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"), Fragment2.class, null);
    return fragmentTabHost;

}
```

The activity class XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.studio3s.myapplication.TestActivity">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.studio3s.myapplication.FragmentTabs"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I see no tabs on my activity..where can be the problem?

Fragment1 and 2 classes are just empty fragments with just one textview..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use childFragmentManager instead FragmentManager i.e.
`fragmentTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.content);`

Here `conent` is where you want to shown current fragment. now your container will contains tabs which you add in fragmentTabHost

Comment: Changed to   fragmentTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),R.id.content); in my fragmentTabs class, and edited the fragment xml to http://pastebin.com/RnXBaV62 . Still, nothing.. And also, the onAttach function is called for my FragmentTabs class..

Comment: my suggestion is to use `FrameLayout` in case of `LinearLayout`

Comment: Same output..http://pastebin.com/qUj8YEHm..Do you know any tutorials to do something like this http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9U6gX0XYC5Y/UZ92L8HpLJI/AAAAAAAATiU/eRzkdGVLLSw/s1600/sample1.png , but not with actionbar.. I want to do this inside a fragment..

Comment: Nevermind.. I followed this tutorial http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/ , and after 3 hours everything is ok! haha! Thanks for you help anyways!